# How can I apply some value with HTML tags to a form element?

Tags: forms

I've assigned some value with HTML tags to a form element, say the element is called `name`.

When it returns the form, it exactly prints the value along with the HTML. What I want in return instead, is the style applied to the text.

In this what I'm trying to do is hook_form_FORMID_alter().
This is the page where comments are listed(admin/content/comment). In this, for each comment I'm showing the subject comment and author etc. Also a collapsible tree for editing the comment with pre filled values in the fields.

```
$form['name'] = '<b>Fazeela</b>'
return $form;
```

Comment: What type of element is $form['name']? Are you talking about text that is in a text field or text area?

Comment: when referencing code, please post the code here, not a link to the code - if the link dies, the question will be useless for future people viewing it

Comment: It is not a field, there is a collapsible tree, in which I am printing this value.

Comment: May you provide the full code of that function, and explain exactly what is wrong in the result you are obtaining?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Hi, I have edited the code and requirement. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use css.

Example:

If your `$form['name']` is a div with an id `wrapper`,

```
<div id="wrapper">Fazeela</div>
```

Include a css file in your module file, particularly in hook_init function.

```
function NameOfYourModule_init(){
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path("module", "NameOfYourModule") . "/mycss.css"); 
}
```

mycss.css file

```
#wrapper{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Did you see the code?

Comment: Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra There is no need to include a CSS style file for rendering something in bold. See my answer.